# Auto-map all fields except one, which should be passed through some other function

Tags: java, mapstruct

Using Mapstruct, how can I create a mapper which would auto-map all but one (or two, three, etc.) fields which should be passed through some custom mapping logic?

**Mapper**

```
@Mapper
public interface MyEntityMapper
{
    MyEntityMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyEntityMapper.class);

    @Mappings(
        {
            @Mapping(source = "createdByPerson.id", target = "createdByPersonId"),
        })
    MyEventPayload toEventPayload(MyEntity entity);
}
```

If I have a `someString` field which needs some custom mapping logging to be done first, how would I do that? I see this `argument` option to `@Mapping`, but that seems a bit crazy to write java code within a string within an annotation!

I was hoping to do something like:

```
@MappingFor(MyEntity.class, "someString")
default String mapSomeString(String value) {
    return value + " custom mapping ";
}
```

**Update**

I found `@AfterMapping` and used it e.g.:

```
@AfterMapping
public void mapSomeString(MyEntity entity, MyEventPayload payload) {
    // do fancy stuff here
}
```

But I'm still curious if you can provide per-field after-mapping / custom-mapping functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to map a single field in a specific way you can use [Mapping methods selection based on qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).

This looks something like

```
@Mapper
public interface MyEntityMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "someString", qualifiedByName = "myFancyMapping")
    MyEventPayload toEventPayload(MyEntity entity);

    @Named("myFancyMapping") // org.mapstruct.Named
    default String mapSomeString(String value) {
        return value + " custom mapping ";
    }
}
```

You can also use `Mapping#qualifiedBy` and construct your own `Qualifier` (`org.mapstruct.Qualifier`) annotation.

This looks like:

```
@Qualifier // org.mapstruct.Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface MyFancyMapping {
}

@Mapper
public interface MyEntityMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "someString", qualifiedBy = MyFancyMapping.class)
    MyEventPayload toEventPayload(MyEntity entity);

    @MyFancyMapping
    default String mapSomeString(String value) {
        return value + " custom mapping ";
    }
}
```

#### Alternative

An alternative would be to do the custom mapping in an `@AfterMapping` or with an expression (I don't recommend using expressions, as it is error prone).

Comment: Thanks. I used `@AfterMapping` but will checkout these other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `Expressions` of MapStruct?

Here is example from Docs:

```
@Mapping(target = "timeAndFormat",
     expression = "java( new org.sample.TimeAndFormat( s.getTime(), s.getFormat() ) )")
```

Instead of `new org.sample.TimeAndFormat...` you could use your class constructor or method.

Comment: Yes, but I refuse to do that. ;-) `@AfterMapping is the correct answer IMO. Unless I'm missing some other feature. Thanks!

Comment: I think that you are looking at mapping method qualifiers, have a look at me answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @AfterMapping e.g.:

```
@AfterMapping
public void mapSomeString(MyEntity entity, MyEventPayload payload) {
    // do fancy stuff here
}
```